# Rocky 8.5 - Alternate repo for sshpass, removed from EPEL

Tags: rhel, kickstart, sshpass

BACKGROUND:

I am developing a Kickstart file to install Rocky (8.5), and I have included EPEL as a repo in order to install Ansible.  Yesterday, when trying to install from my Kickstart file, I received a message that "nothing provides sshpass needed by ansible-2.9.27-1.el8.noarch"

A quick search yielded this page: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=2020679

Since Red Hat just released RHEL 8.6 a few days ago, it seems that sshpass was removed from EPEL.  Since Rocky will naturally be a little behind RHEL, I am expecting that I will not be able to get this package from Rocky's repos until they release 8.6 in a week or two or whenever.

QUESTION:

Until Rocky 8.6 is released, what repo should I add (temporarily) to my Kickstart file to get past this dependency issue?

Comment: Just so you are prepared, a newer Ansible will be available in the 8.6 AppStream repo (with `ansible-core` as the package, version 2.12).  So you won’t need EPEL.  There are some things to consider in the 2.9->2.12 update, though, so prepare now.

Comment: Thank you for the heads up.  I will be sure to look into this before going to 8.6, once its available from Rocky.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Old versions of EPEL](https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/archive/epel/) are still available so you can try to use the 8.5 archived version:

```
https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/archive/epel/8.5.2022-05-10/Everything/x86_64/
```

Comment: Yes! Thank you.  I figured that there must be an archive somewhere, I just wasn't sure where to find it.

Answer (score 0):

sed command to patch your repo:

```
sed -i 's|^metalink=https://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/metalink?repo=epel-$releasever&arch=$basearch&infra=$infra&content=$contentdir|baseurl=https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/archive/epel/8.5.2022-05-10/Everything/x86_64/|' /etc/yum.repos.d/epel.repo
```

Comment: This permanently changes EPEL to point at an archive space to solve a problem that will resolve itself when 8.6 comes out.  You should at least show how to revert the change.